# Can't change a property in an event receiver

Tags: 2013

I have an event receiver in a form library and in the `itemadded` event I can change the name of the file but it is not working when I try to change a property called "Reference Number", even when I see the value of the property; I put below the code:

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemAdded(properties);



    // aqui podemos cambiar el nombre a los archivos que se han añadido a la lista ...
    string Area = "";
    string reference_number = "";

    if (properties.AfterProperties["Area"] != null)
        Area = properties.AfterProperties["Area"].ToString();

    if (properties.AfterProperties["Reference Number"] != null)
        reference_number = properties.AfterProperties["Reference Number"].ToString();

    if (!Area.Equals(""))
    {
        // lets see the amount of files with this Area
        SPQuery query = BuildArbitraryQuery(properties.List, "Area", Area, true);
        int count = properties.List.GetItems(query).Count;

        SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
        string newFileName = Area + "-" + (count + 1).ToString().PadLeft(3, '0') + "-" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
        string newReference = Area + "/" + (count + 1).ToString().PadLeft(3, '0') + "/" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "/" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');

        item["Name"] = newFileName;

        // this is the property I want to change and that doesnt works.
        item.Properties["Reference Number"] = newReference;

        try
        {
            properties.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            EventFiringEnabled = false;

            item.Update();
        }
        finally
        {
            properties.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            EventFiringEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

update: I found the solution, although I can see the properties I promoted from infopath to the form library I can't change them, to change them I need to access the xml file that belongs to the item. I do it this way and it worked. if you know any other solution please tell me.

Comment: Is your intent to set the "Reference Number" property bag value or rather a field on the list item by the same name? Assuming the former, you need to call Update() on Properties, too, not just on the list item itself.

Comment: thanks nsturdivant, my problem was that I was working with form libraries and I was trying to modify a property that was in the xml file of the item and not in the item, now that I know that I have to access the xml file it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, although I can see the properties I promoted from infopath to the form library I can't change them, to change them I need to access the xml file that belongs to the item. I do it this way and it worked. if you know any other solution please tell me.